# How to track down a Python/Django/uwsgi/nginx timeout

Tags: python, django, nginx, timeout, uwsgi

I've got the following setup...

- nginx listens on public port 80 and proxies requests to `localhost:10000`
- uwsgi running django site 1 listens on localhost:10000 and generates some webpages. It also makes some calls to a webservice on `localhost:10001`
- uwsgi running django site 2 listens on `localhost:10001` and amongst other things, It makes some calls to a webservice on `otherhost:1234`

When `otherhost` is busy, some requests are expected to take up to 10 minutes to complete. Unfortunately, after exactly 2 minutes, nginx gives a `502 Bad Gateway`.

As far as I can see, the problem has to be one of...

#### nginx timeout:

I believe this is unlikely as that would be a 504 but I'm using:

```
proxy_read_timeout 1800;
proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
```

#### uwsgi #1 timeout:

I'm launching uwsgi like this (in both cases)

```
nohup uwsgi --http :8000 --chdir /opt/Path/To/Project --module Project.wsgi
            --virtualenv /opt/pyenv --enable-threads --logto /var/log/LogFile.log -p 1
            --threads 50 -t 1800 2> /dev/null &
```

#### Django site 1 calling site 2:

The call is being made like this:

```
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(Url, urlencode(Data).encode("utf-8"), 
               timeout=1800).read().decode("utf-8")
```

#### Site 2 calling othersite:

This is being done by a library which uses the `HTTPConnectionPool`. I've configured a timeout of 10 minutes. I think this is unlikely as setting it to (say) 2s results in an Http 500 on timeout...

I've scanned my codebase for `timeout` (and `120`, `120000`, and even, in desperation `2`) but I can't find anywhere the timeout is being set - I assume it's a default from *something*.

If I skip nginx and do:

```
curl -m1800 -XGET 'http://localhost:10000/UI/Url'
```

I get

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

After exactly one minute.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing? What's a good way to track this one down?

Comment: Anything over a few seconds for a webservice might need a different solution.  Why not use a task queue like django-celery/redis?  Your djangosite2 would add a task to the queue that otherhost:1234 would pick up and complete when it's free.

Comment: A task queue really is the right approach for something like this. django-celery really is the bee's knees and is an extremely useful tool to have in your toolbox.  I've also found myself in projects where I was increasing uWSGI / nginx timeouts everywhere I could find them and my life became much better after implementing django-celery.

Comment: We've already got RabbitMQ queues left right and centre. In fact, the long-running call queries `otherhost` for results and publishes them onto a queue for processing. I'm waiting for the request to return and tell me how many messages were pumped onto the queue (on the order of 50-500k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pretty "strange" setup:

nginx -> uwsgi http router -> uwsgi

instead of

nginx -> uwsgi

maybe you have some good reason for it, but in such a case you need to set the timeout between
uwsgi http router and uwsgi via --http-timeout 1800

If the http router is not you want/need you can just let uwsgi speaks http with the --http-socket option

Comment: I may have been unclear. The 2 uwsgi processes are running on the same host but for logically different purposes. The solution as a whole is provided as an appliance with all the machines in the cluster on a private virtual network (as in, private-per-cluster) except for the nginx port 80 which is bound to a public IPAddress (eg LAN). The first uwsgi process is hosting a django site which uses python libraries to manage connections to the 2nd (Think UI and API)

Comment: i may have been unclear too: it is irrelevant the purpose of your setup, you have an http proxy in the middle and its timeout is by default 60 seconds, you should increase it to the same level of nginx. But i am still unsure if you really understand the difference between --http and --http-socket

Comment: Clearly not. Can you edit your answer, making clear which uwsgi instance you're referring to and explain in more detail? While uwsgi1 sometimes makes calls to uwsgi2 (sometimes not, sometimes multiple times per request). I wouldn't personally call that proxying as processing and transformations occur in the middle. Either we've got a terminology mis-match or one of us is missing something. Thanks :)

Comment: When you use --http instead of --http-socket a proxy is spawned. nginx is connecting to it and this proxy is connecting to the uwsgi instance hosting the app. All happens transparently but effectively you have added another layer in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing [uwsgi_read_timeout](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule).